# class defined inside h1 not responding to css

Tags: html, css

I am using the toolbox theme for wordpress. This is the code used to display the title of each post on the blog page inside an h1 tag

```
<h1 class="entry-title"><a href="<?php t he_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'toolbox' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php     the_title(); ?></a></h1>
```

It is displaying the titles correctly on the page but when i try to edit the appearence of these titles by using css, there is no change, the color still remains blue:

```
.entry-title {color:#000;}
```

There is a strange blue underline beneath the title too, i would also like that to be removed.

Here's the html output of that page:

```
<header class="entry-header">
<h1 class="entry-title">
<a rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to Haley Joel Osment to Try Acting As a Grown Up in New…" href="http://localhost/wordpress/featured/haley-joel-osment-to-try-acting-as-a-grown-up-in-new-6/">Haley Joel Osment to Try Acting As a Grown Up in New…</a>
</h1>
<div class="entry-meta">
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class declaration `.entry-title` does not affect the links within the `h1` element.
If you want to address the links inside the `h1` element you have to use the selector `h1.entry-title a`.

Example to remove the underlines and set the color explicitly:

```
h1.entry-title a { text-decoration:none; color:red; }
```

PS: In this context the prefix `h1.` might be optional, but it offers a more specific differentiation.

Comment: @Christopher: It does not affect the links, not "effect" the links. Also, `h1.entry-title a` is not a "class", it is a CSS selector.

Comment: @Chromium: I guess you mean "It does affect the links, not effect the links"?
But you are right, my lousy choosed phrases might cause confusion. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Chromium (I can't comment on your answer yet due to missing reputation):
Your answer does not consider the h1-prefix. So your selector might not take any effect if somewhere else in the styles the selector `h1.entry-title a` is defined, because this would override your styles.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an `<a>` within an `<h1>` tag and style the `<h1>`, the `<a>` will use it's inherited styling and may not follow the styling of the `<h1`.

Perhaps you might want to just style the `<a>` elements within `.entry-title`:

```
.entry-title a{
//styles
}
```

If it still does not respond, it is possible that there is an issue of specificity, in which case you will want to use `!important` on the `.entry-title` style.

**EDIT**
To remove the blue line from underneath the link on hover, you'll probably want to remove link text decoration:

```
.entry-title a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
    // other styles
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having here is that the browser will put it's default style onto the `<a>` inside the `<h1>` for accessibility reasons and possibly something else.

Ideally, the `<a>` should go outside the `<h1>`, like this:

```
<a href="<?php t he_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'toolbox' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark">
    <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there is another rule with greater [*specificity*](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/css_specificity_wars.html) that is overriding your rule. Either add a `!important` to your rule (`.entry-title {color:#000 !important;}`) or change the selector (the `.entry-title`) part to have a greater [specificity](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg).

For example, with Chrome you can *Inspect* the element by right-clicking on the element and selecting *Inspect element* from the context menu. You should be able to see what other CSS rules are being applied to your element which will help track down what other rule might be applying to the element and overriding your style. Most other modern browsers have a similar *development tool* for inspecting HTML, CSS and JavaScript.

Comment: If you down-vote an answer without a comment you are not helping at all.

Comment: Thank You everyone for all ur answers, Christopher's answer did the trick for me!

Comment: @Sheikh: If you take a look at my answer, you'll see it's the same as Christopher's, except I explained why it works.